# Original title of timeline object always displaying even when changed

Tags: facebook-timeline

I create a timeline object called 'Reward Gold'.  Initially it's Title parameter is set to 'Sample Reward Gold'.  I change it to 'Gold' and save it.  When I review it's settings, I see it set to 'Gold'.  So all should be good.

I then create a timeline action called 'Award Gold'.  I assign it the 'Reward Gold' object.  I make a few minor changes to verb tenses (awarded and is awarding).  I save the action.

When I post the action to the timeline though, I see 'Sample Reward Gold' instead of just 'Gold'.  It's displaying the original Title for the object instead of what I changed it to.

Answer (score 0):

This could just be a bug in the ways sample objects are updated -- can you Debug (aka Lint) the URL for your sample object and check the debug tool?  The Debug tool is here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug